# Remove installed packages from one repo and reinstall from CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos, rpm

I have 62 packages from RPMfusion that have overridden the CentOS upstream packages, and now I would like to return to the original CentOS packages.

The only idea I can think of is

```
BAD_PACKAGES="name1 name2 ..."
echo $BAD_PACKAGES |xargs rpm -e --nodeps
echo $BAD_PACKAGES |xargs yum install
```

But that would leave the system in a broken state during the process.

**Question**

What is the safest way to have those packages removed and then reinstalled from CentOS's repo?

Comment: If they are dependent packages, have you tried yum remove <package>?

Comment: `yum` will try to resolve it by removing all packages that depend and not just the 62 packages.

Comment: Yes if those 62 packages belong to a group, you can do yum remove >group>. What are these 62 packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *upgrade* to older version by using `--oldpackage` option of `rpm`:

```
rpm -Uvh --oldpackage package-a.1.23.rpm
```

This is much safer than `rpm -e --nodeps`. You can upgrade several packages in one command so there will be no broken dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

This following worked, but it was scary as it broke tons of critical services during the process.

```
rpm -qa --queryformat "%{NAME}.%{ARCH} %-35{DISTRIBUTION}\n" | grep -i "rpm-fusion" | awk '{print $1}' > /root/list_arch
cat /root/list_arch | xargs rpm -e --nodeps 
cat /root/list_arch | xargs yum -y install
```

`list_arch` had to be edited a bit as the package names from rpm-fusion was a little different from the original CentOS package names.

I had the output from the `yum` command that installed the rpm-fusion packages which was a big  insurance.